# How to get a list column with values of multiple columns given in another column in Pyspark Dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to create a new column like the Dataframe showed below in Pyspark?

I have been trying List Comprehension:

```
import pyspark.functions as F

df.withColumn('result', [F.col(colname) for colname in F.col('colList')])
```

but doesn´t work.

The expected result is:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+---------------+------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|        colList|result|
+----+----+----+----+----+---------------+------+
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|['col1','col2']| [1,2]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|['col2','col3']| [2,0]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|['col1','col3']| [1,0]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|['col3','col4']| [0,3]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|['col2','col5']| [2,4]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|['col4','col5']| [3,4]|
+----+----+----+----+----+---------------+------+
```

Comment: If you are using Spark 2.40+, you can try `transform()` function to simplify your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Loading requisite functions and creating the DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit, col, struct
from itertools import chain

myValues = [(1,2,0,3,4,['col1','col2']),(1,2,0,3,4,['col2','col3']),
            (1,2,0,3,4,['col1','col3']),(1,2,0,3,4,['col3','col4']),
            (1,2,0,3,4,['col2','col5']),(1,2,0,3,4,['col4','col5'])]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myValues,['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','colList'])
df.show()
+----+----+----+----+----+------------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|     colList|
+----+----+----+----+----+------------+
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col1, col2]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col2, col3]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col1, col3]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col3, col4]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col2, col5]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col4, col5]|
+----+----+----+----+----+------------+
```

As a next step, we create columns for respective columns in array colList.

```
df = df.withColumn('first_col',col('colList')[0])
df = df.withColumn('second_col',col('colList')[1])
df.show()
+----+----+----+----+----+------------+---------+----------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|     colList|first_col|second_col|
+----+----+----+----+----+------------+---------+----------+
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col1, col2]|     col1|      col2|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col2, col3]|     col2|      col3|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col1, col3]|     col1|      col3|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col3, col4]|     col3|      col4|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col2, col5]|     col2|      col5|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col4, col5]|     col4|      col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+------------+---------+----------+
```

List of columns having integer values -

```
concerned_columns = [x for x in df.columns if x not in {'colList','first_col','second_col'}]
print(concerned_columns)
    ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
```

Now, the most important part, we create a mapping between column name and its respective value using [`create_map`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map) function which has been in spark 2.+ onwards.

```
# Maping - (column name, column values)
col_name_value_mapping = create_map(*chain.from_iterable(
    (lit(c), col(c)) for c in concerned_columns
))
```

Finally, applying this mapping to get the values of the columns stored in columns *first_col* and *second_col* and putting them in an array using [`struct`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct).

```
df = df.withColumn('result', struct(col_name_value_mapping[col('first_col')],col_name_value_mapping[col('second_col')]))
df = df.drop('first_col','second_col')
df.show()
+----+----+----+----+----+------------+------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|     colList|result|
+----+----+----+----+----+------------+------+
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col1, col2]| [1,2]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col2, col3]| [2,0]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col1, col3]| [1,0]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col3, col4]| [0,3]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col2, col5]| [2,4]|
|   1|   2|   0|   3|   4|[col4, col5]| [3,4]|
+----+----+----+----+----+------------+------+
```